# How to read watermarks with Python?

Tags: python, watermark

Is there any way to read metadata - watermarks from image files with Python?

Answer (score 3):

If by watermark you mean some "signature" image content added to an image in order to mark it, then no. Such a watermark is merged with the original image and thus an integral part of it. If you mean meta-data info then yes, this can be read: but you don't specify whether you mean programmatically, or what language or stack you're using or would like to use.